# Can redirecting stderr and stdout to one file result in an error?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, error-handling

I'm writing a script that takes files (`filename`...) as arguments, and redirects both the stdout and stderr to a file of name `filename.output`. In the files are commands, and I'd only like to bash once (in case a command within a file should not be run multiple times i.e. `mkdir` or `rmdir`). I have found that, when iterating through the arguments, this command works:

```
bash $a &> "$(basename $a).output"
```

However, I'd also like to use the error status of this command in case `.output` could not be created for whatever reason:

```
if ! bash $a &> "$(basename $a).output"
    then
        echo >&2 "failed to create $(basename $a).output"
fi
```

When I do this, my if statement always evaluates to true, which *I think* is because either stdout or stderr need to fail in redirecting, as opposed to both of them. Very few of the commands I am testing with produce both stderr and stdout (i.e. a command like `date` produces stdout, but no stderr, thus causing a non-zero return value as stderr fails to redirect).

Am I correct in my analysis of why my code is not functioning properly, and if so, is there a way to check for the failure of stdout redirection and stderr redirection individually, so I accurately display when `.output` isn't created?

**EDIT:** I have found that the issue actually lies in the `bash "$a"` component, as any time `$a` is a file with a command that produces an error, the overall if statement evaluates to true. I suppose now my question would be, are there any instances in which redirecting stdout and stderr would result in an error that I should look out for?

Comment: Always double quote your variables when you use them, eg `bash "$a" &> "$(basename "$a").output"` which can be better written as `bash "$a" &> "${a##*/}.output"`

Comment: Meant to say that my if statement always evaluates to true when the command is non-zero, and it seems the command almost aways returns a non-zero number. I'll edit the main post to reflect this.

Comment: Curious: if you can't create the `.output` file why do you think you'd be able to create a corresponding `.error` file in the same place?

Comment: I actually can't imagine a case where `.output` could not be created, it is really just to practice defensive programming.

Comment: It's not defensive if the likelihood of falling to create output is matched by the likelihood of failing to create error. Writing to a different directory or using the system logging subsystem (`logger 'hello, world'`) would seem more prudent

Comment: You can't know from that command if it failed due a redirection failing, or because the script itself failed. There's only one file being opened, so really only one part that can fail. Redirecting both involves some file descriptor duplicating, but I can't see how that could fail, except maybe if there's a limit on open file descriptors or so, but that would be far more unexpected and bigger trouble.

Comment: If you do want to check for the redirections specifically, you'll need to open then separately from running the script. The question is: do you want to?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I guess I don't need to check for redirections specifically, although I am worried that I will possibly miss a failure in stdout/stderr redirection (I don't know if a failure like such is common or not)

Comment: "...any time $a is a file with a command that produces an error, the overall if statement evaluates to true." Presumably "$a" is a bash script; it may have commands in it that produce errors without `bash "$a"` evaluating false, but that depends on how it's written. You can write so it quits with `exit 1` (or other non-zero status) when commands fail, or call it with `bash -e` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
if ! bash $a &> "$(basename $a).output"; then
```

the main branch of the if-statement runs if there is an error in the redirection, or if the script runs but returns a non-zero exit status. The `&> file` operator is the same as `> file 2>&1`, and it redirects both stdout and stderr, but since there's only one file involved, you'd be hard-pressed to find a way to have one of the redirections succeed, but the other to fail. The redirection can fail, for all reasons creating a file can, e.g. permission issues, a non-existing path, disk full.

Let's make a test script: this will just print something, and if it was given an argument, it'll exit with an error.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo test script
if [ "$#" != 0 ]; then
    echo exiting with error
    exit 1
fi
$ chmod +x test.sh
```

Here, the redirection fails (since `./non-existing-dir/` indeed didn't exist):

```
$ if ! ./test.sh > ./non-existing-dir/test.output; then 
    echo "it failed (for some reason)"; fi
bash: ./non-existing-dir/test.output: No such file or directory
it failed (for some reason)
```

Here, the redirection succeeds, and output is collected to the file, but the script itself returns a failing status:

```
$ rm -f test.output
$ if ! ./test.sh 1 > ./test.output; then
    echo "it failed (for some reason)"; fi
it failed (for some reason)

$ cat test.output 
test script
exiting with error
```

You can't miss an error in a redirection; one will cause the command to exit with a non-zero status. But the exact value is not defined and depends on the shell, so we can't use that to tell apart the redirection failing and the script itself failing. The POSIX Shell Command Language definitions says in 2.8.2 Exit Status for Commands:

> If a command fails during word expansion or redirection, its exit status shall be between 1 and 125 inclusive.

Bash's manual says a similar thing in [3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html).

---

Now, if you do want to check an error in the redirection specifically, you *can* do it, you just have to open the redirection separately before running the program. E.g. we can use a script like this to run our program:

```
$ cat redir.sh 
#!/bin/sh

outfile="${1?please define output file}"
cmd="${2?please define command to run}"
shift 2

if ! exec 9> "$outfile"; then
    echo "error: cannot create redirection to '$outfile'"
    exit 1
fi

if ! "$cmd" "$@" >&9 2>&9; then
    echo "error: script '$cmd' failed"
    exit 1
fi
exec 9>&-         # close the output fd
```

Now, the failing redirection is detected as such:

```
$ bash redir.sh ./non-existing-dir/test.output ./test.sh
redir.sh: line 8: ./non-existing-dir/test.output: No such file or directory
error: cannot create redirection to './non-existing-dir/test.output'
```

and so is the script failing:

```
$ bash redir.sh ./test.output ./test.sh 1
error: script './test.sh' failed
```